# Python catch previous exception in broad handler

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Some of my api views have something like this:

```
try:
    do_stuff()
except KeyError as exc:
    logger.log(exc)
    raise APIException("No good")
```

Ideally I don't want to log in every piece of code like this but use a general exception handler that catches APIException, so I changed my code to:

```
try:
    do_stuff()
except KeyError as exc:
    raise APIException(exc)
```

#### exception_handler.py

```
def exception_handler(...):

    logger.log(exc)  # I want to log the KeyError...

    return Response({"message": "try again sam"}, status_code=400)
```

My problem is the exc in the handler isn't the keyerror but the apiexception, can I somehow get the KeyError from sys.exc_info or stacktrace?

Comment: You can try `logger.log(exc.args[0])` since the KeyError was passed to the APIException constructor. But you would have to do more work if you have different Exception-ception levels.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to raise your own exception (here it is `APIException`) and attach the original exception.

You can take a look at [six.raise_from](https://pythonhosted.org/six/index.html#six.raise_from) (if you want a Python 2/3 compatible solution):

> Raise an exception from a context. On Python 3, this is equivalent to `raise exc_value from exc_value_from`. On Python 2, which does not support exception chaining, it is equivalent to raise exc_value.

You can also create your own exception class which can do the chaining.

```
class APIException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, exc_from=None):
        self.exc_from = exc_from
        if exc_from:
            msg += ': raise from {0}'.format(str(exc_from))
        super(APIException, self).__init__(self, msg)

# demo

def do_stuff():
    raise KeyError('bad key')


def main():
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except KeyError as exc:
        raise APIException('error in main', exc)


try:
    main()
except APIException as exc:
    print(str(exc))
```

Of course, instead of printing/logging your APIException error message you can log your original message:

```
try:
    main()
except APIException as exc:
    print(str(exc.exc_from))
```

**Edit: Use class hierarchy for exceptions**

But, if `do_stuff()` is part of your API, it’s a better practice to do the exception handling inside this function and throw your own exception which can inherit `APIException`.

```
class APIException(Exception):
    pass


class BadStuffError(APIException):
    pass


def do_stuff():
    try:
        # ...
        raise KeyError('bad key')
    except KeyError as exc:
        raise BadStuffError('bad stuff: ' + exc.args[0])



def main():
    do_stuff()


try:
    main()
except APIException as exc:
    print(str(exc))
```

This solution is the best, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python 3, you can simply raise the `APIException`:

```
try:
    do_stuff()
except KeyError as exc:
    raise APIException() from exc
```

Then in your exception handler, if `exc` is the `APIException`, you can access the original exception with `exc.__context__`.

```
def exception_handler(exc):
    logger.log(exc.__context__)
    return Response({"message": "try again sam"}, status_code=400)
```

The `from exc` is not actually needed to be able to access `__context__`, but it makes it clear that the `KeyError` was converted to `APIException`, rather than `APIException` being raised during the handling of `KeyError`.
See the [exception docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) for more info.